# Adding JPanel to Canvas

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel

Since JPanel and Canvas are both same-level components, the solution would probably be some sort of a 'hack'. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759983/transparent-jpanel-over-canvas-vlcj) question says that you won't be able to add the lightweight component to the heavyweight canvas (I want JPanel transparent).

If this isn't posible, then would putting a transparent Component work? Also, is it feasible to add Swing components to the Component (it just has to work, even if it's bad). And how would I go about actually putting it over the canvas (since they are both same-level components)?

Note: I would never do something like this in a real app, I just need it in this case

Comment: Are you tied to using a `Canvas`?

Comment: ***Why** are you tied to using a `Canvas`?*  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am provided a Canvas and I want to lay Swing components over it. I can't change the fact that I'm given a Canvas.

Comment: Is the content of the panel static?  What, specifically is in the panel?  ..more information is better than less, when it comes time to explain the 'user feature' that you are trying to provide.  Have you looked at the [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html)?  Java 7 offers the ability to mix Swing and AWT components without artifacts.  Can your app. justify demanding Java 7+?

Comment: Well that is one answer to 4 questions.  1 out of 4 ain't bad, it's a waste of my time.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possiblity is to add the JPanel to whatever container the Canvas is on, then setting the color of the JPanel to have an alpha of 0. This should add it over the old one, without blocking out the Canvas. Is this what you want?

EDIT: Thinking about it, the JPanel's default color is transparent... You should just be able to add the JPanel the Canvas's parent, and lay it over it

Comment: The canvas is in a JFrame. I added the JPanel to it, but it shows up underneath the Canvas.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, hadn't thought about this. The Canvas is a heavyweight component, so it'll still stay on top.
See here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/index.html
Don't think there is a way to do this

Comment: Would it be possible to just use a Panel and add a JPanel to that?

Comment: Yes, but didn't you say you had to use a Canvas?

Comment: No I mean add a Panel to the JFrame and since Panel is also a heavyweight component it will overlap Canvas (right?). Then I could add a JPanel to that.